# odoo10 adding sub menu to another module

Tags: submenu, odoo-10

I am trying to create a sub-menu to Payroll Modules. Tried so many way but i cant make it.

I found this code in forum but it is not working.

```
<menuitem id="menu_test" parent="hr_payroll.menu_hr_payroll_root" name="Test Module Parent"/>
<menuitem id="menu_test_child" parent="menu_test" name="My Menu" action="action_view_hr_module_reports_form"/>
```

Employee Payslips

Payslips Batches

Configuration

```
Salary Structures
Salary Structures Hierarchy
Salary Rules
Contribution Registers
```

These are default sub-menus in payroll and i want to add a new Reports menu. How can i do that?

Someone can help me please? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? Is there any error message when you try to use it? The code you linked looks like it should do well, provided you have an action defined for `action_view_hr_module_reports_form`. Take a look at the [Actions Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/actions.html) and/or some examples from the core code for more details on that. For us to help anymore we need to know what errors you are getting.